# any straightforward way to convert `table` to `matrix`?

Tags: r, matrix, data-conversion

I have a table `tb`, for example

```
tb <- table(mtcars[c("carb","cyl")])
> tb
    cyl
carb 4 6 8
   1 5 2 0
   2 6 0 4
   3 0 0 3
   4 0 4 6
   6 0 1 0
   8 0 0 1
```

where

```
> class(tb)
[1] "table"
```

I am wondering if there is a more straightforward way to convert `tb` from a `table` to `matrix`, i.e.,

```
mtb <- as.matrix(as.data.frame.matrix(tb))
```

such that

```
> mtb
  4 6 8
1 5 2 0
2 6 0 4
3 0 0 3
4 0 4 6
6 0 1 0
8 0 0 1
```

and

```
> class(mtb)
[1] "matrix"
```

This is what I did for the conversion, but I don't think this is straightforward due to using both `as.matrix()` and `as.data.frame.matrix()`.

Appreciated in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do:

```
unclass(table(mtcars[c("carb","cyl")]))
```

Check class:

```
class(unclass(table(mtcars[c("carb","cyl")])))

[1] "matrix"
```

Comment: Thanks! I guess "mtb <- `class<-`(tb,"matrix") " might also be a solution, but yours is more straightforward :)

Comment: I think you can use also that, yes :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
m = matrix(data = tb,nrow = nrow(tb),ncol = ncol(tb),byrow = FALSE,dimnames = list(c(1,2,3,4,6,8),c(4,6,8)))
```